# RxJava Object Transformation

Tags: java, retrofit, rx-java

This is what I want to do:

I need to chain two network calls using RxJava and Retrofit.

1. The first call retrieves an `Observable<User>`.
2. The second call retrieves additional info `Observable<UserAdditionalInfo>`, that needs to be attached to the `Observable<User>` retrieved previously.
3. Then, retrieve the `Observable<User>` with the additional info attached to it.

I've tried with the `flatMap` operator:

```
Observable<User> userObservable = new RestClient().getUserById(1234);
userObservable.flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<?>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<?> call(User user) {
        OtherRestClient otherRestClient = new OtherRestClient();

        // Second network call. It retrieves an Observable<UserAdditionalInfo>
        otherRestClient.getUserAdditionalInfo(user.getUserCode());

        // I think, here should be the code that attaches the additional info
        // to the `user` parameter of the call method and return an Observable<User>

        return null;
    }
}).subscribe(o -> System.out.println(o));
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "attaches the additional info to the `user`"?

Comment: Sure, the User class has some fields empty after the first network call, these fields need to be filled with setter methods of the User class by using the UserAdditionalInfo object retrieved in the second network call, that's what I mean with "attaches".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
Observable<User> userObservable = new RestClient().getUserById(1234);
userObservable.flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<User>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<User> call(final User user) {
        OtherRestClient otherRestClient = new OtherRestClient();

        // Second network call. It retrieves an Observable<UserAdditionalInfo>
        Observable<UserAdditionalInfo> additionalObservable = otherRestClient.getUserAdditionalInfo(user.getUserCode());

        return additionalObservable.map(new Func1<UserAdditionalInfo, User>() {
            @Override
            public User call(final UserAdditionalInfo uai) {
                user.setXXX(uai.getXXX());
                // ... any additional calls
                return user;
            }            
        });
    }
}).subscribe(o -> System.out.println(o));
```

The return type of `userObservable.flatMap(...)` statement, if we omit the `.subscribe(...)` part at the end, is `Observable<User>`.

Comment: The last `return null;` statement is unreachable.

Comment: just posted my own answer.

Comment: removed the unreachable `return null`.

Comment: If I use this approach, the type I get in the `Subscriber.onNext()` method is an Object, I want a `User` type to be available in the `Subscriber.onNext()` method. 

If I print the `Subscriber.onNext()` parameter in this way `o.getClass().getCanonicalName()`, it prints `rx.Observable`

Comment: Do you mean that replacing the `subscribe` call in the above code with  `.subscribe(o -> System.out.println(o.getClass().getCanonicalName()));` prints `rx.Observable`? That seems unlikely, Unless I am missing something here.

Comment: I just ran both pieces of code (this answer and your answer), just to make sure I wasn't mistaken. Both return identical results.

Comment: Only if I change `Observable<?>` to `Observable<User>` in the lines 2 and 4 the subscriber gets a User type in the `onNext` method parameter. I'm compiling with Java 8, not retrolambda (I mention this just in case, as this is a weird behaviour for me).

Comment: Yes, of course. My mistake here. I just copied the code from the question and then made modifications, assuming that you would change those accordingly. Because the wild-card would mean the returned type would be assumed to be Object, regardless of what you returned. Updated the answer.